# Oracle 11g SqlDeveloper connects to remote database but SqlPlus cannot

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

As the title suggests, I am trying to connect to a remote database via VPN. When I connect using SQL Developer, the connection is fine. However when I try to connect using SQLPlus I get the below error

```
ERROR:
ORA-12638: Credential retrieval failed

Enter user-name:
```

I am using the exact same credentials for both *(cannot copy the details here as they are a clients and confidential)*.

Any thoughts as to why SQL Developer acts differently to SQLPlus?

Thanks in advance

K.

Comment: We don't need the actual credentials, but knowing how you're connecting from both would probably be helpful. Are you using TNS for either or both? Or a basic connection SQL Developer, and EZConnect for SQL*Plus, or something else?